# Python3 urllib.request often can't open page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

So, I try to get ticket price from S7 airline site (Then I would like to try predict price changes with help of machine learning).

This little parser gets page with prices, then finds minimum price in selected day with help of BeautifulSoup and then saves it in .csv file.

30 second between requests for "cooling" the server. If get 403 error, then wait 120 minutes and continue. Every 25 requests stop for "cooling".

Problem is that often I get 404 error. I checked some links in browser and they work - pages have opened and all is ok. When I try open only one link, parser does it from time to time but also often return 404 error.

I tried add timeout, but it didn't help.

I am new in programming and maybe make obvious mistakes.

Thank you in advance. And sorry for my English:)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import urllib.request as req
import re
import time
from urllib.error import HTTPError


def loader(dest, dest_large, dep_date):
    url = "http://travelwith.s7.ru/selectExactDateSearchFlights.action?TA=1&TC=0&TI=0&" \
          "CUR=RUB&FLC=1&FLX=false&RDMPTN=false&SC1=ANY&FSC1=1&DD1=2016-%s&" \
          "DA1=SVX&DP1=AIR_SVX_RU&AA1=%s&AP1=AIR_%s&LAN=ru" % (dep_date, dest, dest_large)
    request = req.Request(url,
                          headers={
                              'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0'})
    avia = req.urlopen(request).read()
    soup = BS(avia, 'html.parser')
    if len([re.sub('[^0-9]', '', p.get_text()) for p in soup.find_all("span", class_="radiobutton-text")]) > 0:
        price = min([re.sub('[^0-9]', '', p.get_text()) for p in soup.find_all("span", class_="radiobutton-text")])
    else:
        price = 0
    with open('prices/SVX_%s_%s.csv' % (dest, dep_date), 'a', encoding="utf8") as file:
        file.write(str(time.time())+';'+str(price)+'\n')
    print(date, destination, "OK!",price)


dep_date = ['06-08', '06-15', '06-22', '06-29', '07-01', '07-08', '07-15',
            '07-22', '07-29', '08-01', '08-08', '08-15', '08-22', '08-29',
            '09-01', '09-08', '09-15', '09-22', '09-29', '10-01', '10-08', '10-15']
dest = ['FCO', 'PRG', 'BCN', 'TXL']
dest_large = ['FCO_IT', 'PRG_CZ', 'BCN_ES', 'TXL_DE']

counter = 0
while True:
    for date in dep_date:
        for i, destination in enumerate(dest):
            counter += 1
            try:
                loader(destination, dest_large[i], date)
                time.sleep(30)
            except req.HTTPError as err:
                if err.code == 403: # wait if IP has been banned
                    print(date, destination, "Error 403. Ban, wait 120 minutes!")
                    time.sleep(120 * 60)
                if err.code == 404:
                    print(date, destination, "404. Can't open!")
                    time.sleep(30)
            if counter == 25:
                time.sleep(60 * 35)
                counter = 0
```

Comment: Does it lead to 404 on the random url? Will only one request periodically lead to 404?

Comment: @VadimKey random url. It's mean, that in one cycle some url leads to 404, but on the next cycle the same url correctly works and vise versa. And It is very strange for me(

Comment: Probably that's how S7 protects from crawling. Did you look for QPX Express API (https://developers.google.com/qpx-express/)?

Comment: @VadimKey Wow! It seems to be very good service and suitable for my purpose! Thank you!